# How to implement Decider and Activity workers in AWS Flow Framework using AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, amazon-swf

We have 2 Spring-boot applications for AWS Flow Framework.

The *Decider* worker:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WorkerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(WorkerApplication.class);
        ApplicationContext context = application.run(args);
        WorkflowWorker workflowWorker = context.getBean(WorkflowWorker.class);

        workflowWorker.start();
    }
}
```

And *Activity* worker:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ActivityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(ActivityApplication.class);
        ApplicationContext context = application.run(args);
        ActivityWorker activityWorker = context.getBean(ActivityWorker.class);

        activityWorker.start();
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to implement any/both of these using AWS Lambda Service. I understand how to use Lambda's Function Handler:

```
public interface RequestHandler<I, O> {
    O handleRequest(I var1, Context var2);
}
```

But I have no idea how to apply it to our SWF since the workers **poll** for tasks from AWS.

Thanks!

EDIT:

As answered by Maxim Fateev, it is possible to treat lambda tasks as activities, but not for the decider/s.

When I tried it on our SWF under region **ap-southeast-1**,
it was returning an error:

```
ScheduleLambdaFunctionFailed [with EventId 5] selected
Cause: LAMBDA_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_REGION
Decision Task Completed Event Id    : 4
Event Timestamp: Mon Oct 03 09:58:05 GMT+800 2016
```

But when run on region **eu-west-1**, it completed successfully.

It seems that as of this time, swf to lambda calls, although available, are not yet working properly for some regions (like ap-southeast-1). *These are not specified in the current documentation*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWF Service supports invocation of Lambda functions instead of activities. See [Implementing AWS Lambda Tasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/lambda-task.html) section of [AWS Flow Framework for Java Programming Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/welcome.html). Unfortunately there is no way to bind a decider as a Lambda Function yet.